# How can I use Python / regex to move one part of a string to another position in the string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to use Python and regex  to re-order the parts of `input_string` below using `':'` and `%` as reference points:

```
input_string = "old % habits die % hard :(it's difficult to get rid of old habits)"
```

the code should take content from the `":"` until the end of string and then move this chunk earlier into the string, placing the chunk before the second `%` and after the last word between the `%` in the input sentence. Anything that was after the second `%` but not part of the post : chunk should remain.

i.e. - the output string will look something like this:

```
"old % habits die:(it's difficult to get rid of old habits)% hard "
```

Note, " chunk is always towards the end, but the order of where the % chunk is not always consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, regex can do all the job for you. So you could use capturing groups which is flexible enough and more expressive and short than messing around with an array.

```
import re

string = "old % habits die % hard :(it's difficult to get rid of old habits)"

# define a regex that makes the groups you need
rgx = r"(.+%)(.+)(%)(.+)(:.+)$"

# just to illustrate, you would get this groups in the regex

re.match(rgx, string).groups()

# output
# ('old %',
# ' habits die ',
# '%',
# ' hard ',
# ":(it's difficult to get rid of old habits)")

# then you only need to declare the new sorting order 
# in the replacement with the use of grouping.
re.sub(rgx,  "\g<1>\g<2>\g<5>\g<3>\g<4>", string)
```

This two lines would be simpler than any sorting done with an array, plus, it would be more verbose in terms of code clarity.

Comment: thanks Mike, I don't understand yet how it is that the g<n> notation works every time but it does, very simple and also new horizons, thanks again

Comment: If you want more explanation just say what you do not understand and I may be able to explain further or point out some docs. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help Mike, I've got it now. The circle brackets represent the groups, the 5th group in my list is always fifth, and needs to go in front of the second % in any case, irrespective of any other features in the line. The way you wrote it is very clear, I'm just not very good at clarifying this in my head.

Answer (score 1):

If it always is this consistent, you should use something like the following

```
re.split(r"[\%\:]","*old* % habits die % *hard* **:(it's difficult to get rid of old habits)**")
```

This outputs

```
['*old* ',
 ' habits die ',
 ' *hard* **',
 "(it's difficult to get rid of old habits)**"]
```

and you can reorder as necessary and put back any delimiters.

Comment: thanks David, the % position does vary, the : chunk is always at the end. I assume this does mean that the processing is consistent, and that the : chunk will always be the last line, which is always to be joined to the third-last line.